# Set carriage return type for writematrix

Tags: matlab, encoding, carriage-return

I am trying to write data to a text file using [`writematrix`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html).

```
 writematrix([ 1 2 3 4 5 6]' ,'patate.txt')
```

MATLAB encodes it by default as `UTF-8`, and uses a Windows style return (CR LF) (example in Notepad++) :

[image: CR LF in notepad]

The name-value pair `'Encoding'` can be passed to `writematrix`, but the documentation is not explicit on how to use it for the system type:

```
 writematrix([ 1 2 3 4 5 6]' ,'patate.txt', 'Encoding','UTF-8')
```

Is it possible to configure `writematrix`, or use another function, to have `UTF-8` encoding but with Unix style returns (LF)?

Comment: It should be somewhere within the `'encoding'` name-value pair I think. I haven't gotten the function yet, but doing `edit writematrix` should open the function in the editor window. In that there might be a list of possible encodings

Comment: @Adriaan : it is indeed a good idea to go deeper into the nested function : 

Ultimately, `fopen` is called but with a parameter set by default : `'n'` which unfortunately means : `'native'      or 'n' - local machine format - the default`. Therefore I cannot change CR LF with `writematrix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that I cannot change the carriage return to Unix format `writematrix`.

Thanks to [Adriaan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909962/set-carriage-return-type-for-writematrix?noredirect=1#comment123580518_69909962) I looked deeper into the source of `writematrix`. A some point, `writeTextFile` is called and calls `fopen` here:

```
% Open the file for writing
if strcmp(encoding,'system')
    [fid,errmsg] = fopen(file,'Wt'); % text mode: CRLF -> LF
else
    [fid,errmsg] = fopen(file,'Wt','n',encoding); % text mode: CRLF -> LF
end
```

The `encoding` parameter will be used in the `else` condition and `fopen` is called with a default parameter set to `'n'`, which means  `'native'      or 'n' - local machine format - the default`

Therefore I cannot force the carriage return style.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I guess you could save it with a UNIX-style carriage return when saving from a (virtual) UNIX machine then.

Comment: yes, it could be a solution, it is may be a bit overkill . I think i will write my data with a custom function :( , I was happy to find `writematrix` as it is supposedly fast

Comment: If you are on Windows, I presume it's not a shared MATLAB installation. So you should be able to edit the code to open as `'W'` instead of `'Wt'`. -- Note that the `'n'` native flag relates to byte ordering, and does not affect newline characters.

Comment: @CrisLuengo or even copy the entire function, call it `MyWriteMatrix` or something, to definitely not screw up any defaults.

Comment: As of R2021a, the code for this has moved; it's now in `matlab.io.internal.writing.writeTextFile`, lines 34-42. Still unconditionally uses the `'t'` flag for the write mode to do "text mode", which enables dos/unix CRLF translation. I'd consider this a flaw in `write*`: it's 2021; there's use cases for producing either DOS or Unix-mode files on whatever OS you're running on. IMHO this is worth reporting to MathWorks Tech Support (support@mathworks.com) as a feature request to add an arg to the `write*` function to control DOS/Unix mode in the output.

Comment: To get it working now, you can always `writematrix`, then read the file back in, `str2 = strrep(str, sprintf('\r'), '')` it, and write it back out (through a file handle that doesn't have the `'t'` flag on its write mode).